# App Store: Profitability for Game Developers

Tags: ios, game-industry, monetization, appstore

Recent days, I've been spending significant time in discovering chances of profitability of AppStore for developers.

I have found many articles. Some of them are highly optimistic, while other are extremely skeptical. [This article](http://communities-dominate.blogs.com/brands/2010/06/full-analysis-of-iphone-economics-its-bad-news-and-then-it-gets-worse.html) is extremely skeptical. It even claims to have backed its conclusions by objective sales numbers. [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/technology/2009/02/who_profits_from_the_app_store.html) is another pesimistic article saying that games developed by single individuals get 20 downloads a day.

Can I kindly ask to clarify from business viewpoint **whether average developers publishing games and software on AppStore can cover their living expenses, even, whether they can become profitable?**

Is it achievable to generate revenues of 50.000 USD yearly on AppStore for a single developer?

I would like to stay as realistic as possible. Despite the question might look subjective, a good business man will be able to esitmate chances for profitability and prosperity within AppStore.

Comment: This is one of those questions that have no answers. It depends on your game. What is an average developer? How much games are you going to publish, and how much are you going to put into advertising? The only realistic thing is if you try it yourself.

Comment: @DMan: if you take a look at the [article](http://communities-dominate.blogs.com/brands/2010/06/full-analysis-of-iphone-economics-its-bad-news-and-then-it-gets-worse.html), I reffer in my question to, you see, that it is possible to answer this question. The article does it in excellent way. However, it is so skeptical, that I came here to discuss it. **All the business is about numbers, prognosis, esitmates, statistics.** Which means, assuming that all the developers strive to publish their best, what are their chances so be successful?

Comment: @Bunkai. Satori - As I have stated, there is simply too many variables. Some games just take off 'for some reason' and other, perhaps better games, don't. If you want one answer though, then their chances are slim due to the massive amount of apps and established brands. Not to say you can't try, because apps made by one person (like Tiny Wings) can be phenomenal successes.

Comment: @DMan: **I believe, this question is asked thousand times within every developer.** I is definitelly worth of discussing it in detail, and to analyze the situation of iPhone software developer's chances for succcess. For example, is it worth quitting a stable job, to start developing for iPhone? People should be able to answer this question, accepting that there is still area for deviation from average. To make things easier: from 50k developers (I think there is so many of them) how many generate profits?

Comment: There is no problem to solve here, just asking for opinions, highly subjective.

Comment: In 50k developers, an average of about exactly 1134 make profit. No seriously, there is no answer to stuff like this because it depends on the quality of the product. You can't generalize statements and say "the average developer will make this and that" because it will be completely irrelevant to your decision of quitting a job to develop iPhone apps. Can you make profit? Sure. How? Nobody knows exactly, otherwise there would be a lot more iPhone millionaires out there. It depends on a mixture of quality of app in relation to its cost, quality of advertisement, and last but not least, luck.

Comment: @Maik: Do you say, that there is no objective information on the state of AppStore and chances to be successful in there? I am not asking for opinions. I am asking for reliable analysis, a link that covers the situation of profitability from AppStore. If you check the linke article, you will see that it is pretty objective.

Comment: If you don't make it to the top of the list you won't make any money. Angry Birds is more than medicore to not say ****, the marketing did everything for the game to be at the top of the list, so it sold units. You also need to take into account that if such a poor game can sell so many units on the platform whether you should be trying to make games for the platform of just digital toys.

Comment: @Bunkai No, I said a) there is no problem to solve here and b) the word profitability is highly subjective, hence it's not a proper question. That's all, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @3nixios: +1, and thanks for your reply. I am looking for information like this. The article above says, there are less than 1% of applications making millions, and remaining 99% make less than 500USD/year per application. This indicates that stepping into this business will be highly risky. I need to help with evaluation, what are chances of single developer to be successful in this area, if he does his best.

Comment: @Maik: Yeah, I know what you mean. Despite the fact that this question can look vague, a businessman would know how to estimate it. I would like to get to business evaluation of starting a venture as iPhone software developer.

Comment: @Bunkai right, I think you need an economical consultant specifically for your region of the world. Don't get me wrong, game devs are unually not too good at economics ;)

Comment: @Maik: I am really disappointed, how most of responses (not just you) do not wish to take a look from business viewpoint to profitability on AppStore. It is so basic question, in my opinion. Every Indie must find a way how to answer it. Ex: if 95% are not successful while 5% are, then it is highly risky to enter this area. But if 80% are successful, while 20% are not, then it is pretty attractive environment.

Comment: Maybe because we don't believe in statistics. I mean how do you measure successfull objectively? My advice is: don't trust statistics, ask an expert. As I said, game devs are not economical experts, especially not for your region.

Comment: @Maik: I see what you mean. Well, asusming tha game development is a busines, a successful business is, when revenues is higher than expenditures. So the net profit is positive, and the business can keep existing and growing.

Comment: the guy just wanted to sell his own Paratrooper clone. Why -5? :D

Comment: @mhambra: Yeah, I don't believe my own yes. -5 for a fair question, that is essential to everyone? It is like, "I wish to have eyes closed and live in dark, rather than spotting reality".

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - This is because the question is too general of a topic. The truth is, no one knows if it's going to be profitable for you. Looking at statistics to see how profitable it is for someone isn't going to help you at all. There is no 'average' developer. Besides, for market research like these, companies pay thousands (not to say that they are always accurate).

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - To be fair, I think I'll add that you should not quit your job just to make apps. However, don't give up either. Work on them in your spare time. You might get some good supplementary income, and who knows, if it takes off, quit your job. If you're really serious, joining a company may be a good idea.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori, it's more like "walking with one eye closed by a pirate patch" - I mean, [see the answer]

Comment: @DMan: I asked in general, rather than for me.. I asked about sales statistic/per game in mobile game industry. I am repeating this all around. If people do not know, it does not mean, this is bad question. OMG, it requies just little imagination, to understand how vital this question is. You folks really do not care, whether the business you are in is profitable and whether you can make any money with nights spent over PCs instead of having a walk with your girl? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori, there's no business in most cases - if you're writing highschool diploma projects for $1.5k/week, it doesn't means that you actually graduated in the same speciality as the diploma you made..

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - The problem is that the sales statistic per game is highly skewered by highly profitable developers. In general, don't expect more than a hundred sales on any given game. In something as crowded as the app store, good luck selling any copies. If you break through though, then it just keeps on giving ;)

Comment: DMan: Yes, and this is problem. If a developer decides founding a business in the area of iPhone/mobile Game Developmet, he has minimum chances for survival. It is even difficult for single person to create product, that woudl be competitive to products by Gameloft or to other best games in the market, so people would see it as really outstanding and start spreading word about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it achievable to generate revenues of 50.000 USD yearly on AppStore for a single developer?

Of course it is, I can simply point to a single example of this being the case and it's "achievable".  The thing is, in order for *you* to do it there are a lot of factors at play.

Can you make games quickly/cheaply?  With the race to the bottom in terms of purchasing price, if you eat up too much time and money on a single game you're not likely to get any return on that investment

Do you monetize properly?  The freemium model is getting more and more popular, for example.  If you're not going freemium, you need to know how to price yourself in the market.  You have to be fulfilling some kind of strong desire to place yourself above the $1 price point.

Are the games you're making high enough quality that people will *want* to tell their friends about them?  Word of mouth is a very strong sales driver.  If people aren't saying "hey you should play this", you're not going to make any money.

Is the content of the games appealing to the mass market?  You can't just target the 17-34 male demographic with the games you're making if you want to go really wide with it.

Can you advertise properly?  This isn't a case where "if you build it they will come".  You have to send out demo codes to the right people.  Try to get reviewed.  Try to get popular bloggers, etc. to recommend it.  Be active in community groups (facebook, forums, youtube, etc.).

Basically, the point that a lot of people in the comments are making is that it seems you're asking for the impossible analysis.  You're giving a specific profitability number without talking about *the product* you're making *at all*.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for your answer. To be honest, I am aware of all of those variables. Of course, there are factors that distinguish good game from a bad one. But maybe, there are some statistics saying, _this_ percentage out of 350k games got profitable, and _this_ percentage got highly profitable. This would give good estimate how realistic is to be successful in AppStore.

Comment: @Bunkai: The problem with statistics is that they don't paint the whole picture.  Sure, your "average game" didn't make that much money, but the barrier to entry is *so low* that you can't really look at that.  People are putting crappy clones upon clones out there, and maybe $500 per game is actually making some of them money.  All I can say is that every game I've shipped on the app store has made a lot more than that article you linked to calculated, but I would say the quality of those games is drastically above "average".

Comment: I've just checked all your games and they look really entertaining and beautiful. Would you mind tho share, if you were the only developer who created graphics, code, music, and idea? Would you share, please, how much time did it take for you to create one such game?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would run as far away as fast as possible from the AppStore.

If you are aiming for iPad, iPhone, you need some really good marketing to get the initial market penetration. Without this, your App will fall into the oubliettes of the AppStore, which is much more difficult to navigate on a handheld than on a PC.

You also need to think about your game development if you are aiming at portable platforms. You need 'casual' games; games with short game sessions (5-10 mins) that have good feedback and make the player want to continue.

If this is what you are looking at, I would definately try to use something like Unity so you can aim for Android and iPhone with the same source (but it will cost more), and maybe make a PC version available; if your game is really good and people want to play it while going to work, they'll buy it.

If the question was about App Hubs in general (which I doubt) lots of Indie developers go for Steam, I remember reading a 2DBoy article (World of Goo) saying the guys at Steam were cool and they managed to negociate the percentages.

Of course the beauty about using Unity is that you could also sell a PC version.

In any case, I would search for project post-mortems from Indie developers that make AppStore games, and maybe even try and contact some.

GLHF.

Comment: +1, thank you for this message. It vas very valuable. [This article](http://communities-dominate.blogs.com/brands/2010/06/full-analysis-of-iphone-economics-its-bad-news-and-then-it-gets-worse.html) seems to be so persuasive: it divides the revenues sold to developers by number of paid games published. The result says that **a game averagely generates $500 yearly**. Thi is too low. And it is in accordance to what you say.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori That is very low. The problem is that as an initial investment if you are using Unity for example the initial package would be 400$, 1500$ for the Pro version, add another 400$ to that if you want to target Android too. It could maybe be a future option when you have money to spare or a good IP with a user-base already, or if the development will be quick and painless.

Comment: yeah, but if you wish to have really outstanding game developed as an individual, creating graphics will take you several months only. Putting everything together, well, one should estimate more than one year of development time, if the game should be competitive to top selling games. Is it even possible to achieve game quality comparable to top games released by Gameloft or EA? Those companies release game, with predictable success - as they offer unique entertainment experience.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Yes but on portable devices I don't believe that it is what you and I would qualify as a 'good game' that will sell the best. I knwo that jhocking on this site has made an iPhone game, he could maybe give some insight on that.

Comment: 3nixios: maybe you are right, that those games brought by Gameloft or EA might not necessarily be considered as the best games. In my opinion, however, those games offer quality that maximizes chances to be commercialy successful. The games should return profits. And if that is happening, the business can go on, and keep creating, although none of their games will ever be #1.

Answer (score 1):

More than a half of the market games are really:

- school projects
- a result of investments into casual (freelance) programmers (teachers are paying for guitar sheet and chemical apps, animation studios are putting out cartoon toys for children - I ever seen a Nickelodeon themed netbook)

And the most of other projects are developed as any other shareware (what the thing with the amateur game developers calling shareware a freemium? did they completely missed a good class on CS history?), that formalizes a normal workflow of *"how much we're paying to our outsourced programmers, we need that game TBD in a month or so"*. So if you're writing a casual shareware - sit down, start coding, and get ready to reap some minor profits.

Or, say to yourself "I'm about to create a multiplatform game where user needs to throw * from  * to hit * off the *", think about it, and keep coding - having a warm feeling of doing something new || something of personal interest. But the end is very same, unless you're suddenly able to take this project to your boss and ask him for letting you code games in a work hours, asking him also to fund the project (e.g. buying MacBooks for a home-brew team - one for a cat, one for a dog).

Comment: @mhambra: +1, very good answer indeed. It would mean, that most of the players do not see this place as a source of income. They just put there lower quality products with hope, they can make some pocket money. This woudl mean, that perceiving AppStore as a main source of income would mistake.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori they're expecting some income, that is certainly based on the amount of time and money they put in (e.g. if you're going to play roulette with $100, you'll likely lose $100 or win $200 - yet in programming, you may lose $50k job because of spending work time on writing that games).

it seems smarter to write ad-supported games (if you make a coffee cup adventure for a town cafe for $300, it's better than expecting 300*$1 shareware sales), than producing a large volume of shareware/casual games.

Comment: @mhambra: understood.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori but sometimes indie games are way too good for invested time/money.. see `fl0w` (not for IOS, though)

Comment: @mhambra: it looks really fascinating. It looked like it has been released by Sony. I have never seen something like that. Really nice indeed.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori, its Playstation Network, not Sony itself.. lets see wiki: ` Flow (stylized as flOw) is an indie video game created by Jenova Chen and Nicholas Clark. Originally released as a free Flash game in 2006 to accompany Chen's master's thesis, it was reworked into a 2007 PlayStation 3 game by his development studio, Thatgamecompany. .. The game's design is based on Chen's research into dynamic difficulty adjustment at the University of .. ` - so, good idea, hours of coding, and only then the budget (sponsored by own company) to port it to PS3/PSP..

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/571/discussion-between-mhambra-and-bunkai-satori)

Comment: My cat cant use a mac book, he can only barely type coherently on my win 7 laptop.

Comment: @Skeith, it's still ok - you just go and report to your customers that your team also hired a disabled member, who can use only Windows laptops.